# Give second stylesheet to sidebar plugin also used on a page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, stylesheet

how can I change the look of the plugin I'm using on a page (template) without affecting how it looks on a sidebar? here's the following php that I'm using on that template

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: hot
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="content-title">
What's Hot
<a href="javascript: void(0);" id="m"<?php if ($_COOKIE['mode'] == 'list') echo '     class="flip"'; ?>></a>
</div>

<?php if (function_exists('wpp_get_mostpopular')) wpp_get_mostpopular(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your plugin output in a div, you could target it directly in CSS.

```
<div id="something-unique">
    <?php if (function_exists('wpp_get_mostpopular')) wpp_get_mostpopular(); ?>
</div>
```

In the css, you could then start off your selectors with `#something-unique` to target the template only.